# Does link_to always use GET and button_to always POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It seems, if no :method specified, link_to is always GET and button_to, POST.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the specs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), yes, you are correct. `link_to` just generates an `<a>` tag, so that's definitely just a `GET`. If you don't specify otherwise, `button_to` does generate a `POST`.